# Оптимизация кода на Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

```
override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T = when {
    modelClass.isAssignableFrom(M1ViewModel::class.java) -> M1ViewModel(dataManager, schedulerProvider)
    modelClass.isAssignableFrom(C1ViewModel::class.java) -> C1ViewModel(dataManager, schedulerProvider)
    modelClass.isAssignableFrom(C2ViewModel::class.java) -> C2ViewModel(dataManager, schedulerProvider)
    else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class: " + modelClass.name)
} as T
```

вот сам код

Как можно минимизировать код, чтобы каждый раз не писать

```
modelClass.isAssignableFrom(C2ViewModel::class.java) -> C2ViewModel(dataManager, schedulerProvider)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    if(modelClass.superclass == BaseViewModel::class.java) {
        val cArg = arrayOfNulls<Class<*>>(2)
        cArg[0] = DataManager::class.java
        cArg[1] = SchedulerProvider::class.java

        val cls = modelClass.getDeclaredConstructor(*cArg).newInstance(dataManager, schedulerProvider)
        return cls
    }else{
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class: " + modelClass.name)
    }
```

Смог реализовать вот так.

P.S. не синьор, только перехожу на жава и котлин